# How to append div on screen resize

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to replace div positions when specific screen size is reached like css media queries.
I tried it but getting some problems getting the screen size.
Here is what i have done till now.

http://jsbin.com/izize3/60/edit

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width >= 768 || width <= 979) {
        $('#div1').appendTo('#container');
    } else if (width > 979) {
        alert("else if is executed");
        $('#div2').appendTo('#container');
    } else {
        alert("Default else");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you are using in first if statement:

```
if (width >= 768 || width <= 979)
```

Any width > 768 will pass this condition.

You should use instead:

```
if (width >= 768 && width <= 979)
```

BTW, please consider for debugging to use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`.

http://jsbin.com/izize3/73/edit